# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program Exec failed android

Tags: java, android

I have the below java code

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

BufferedReader reader = null;

try
{
    Process mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ip neigh");

    reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( mIpAddrProcess.getInputStream() ) );

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        doMyStuff();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below are some crash logs

```
W System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/system/bin/ip": error=375259648, Exec failed  
W System.err:   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)    
W System.err:   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:698)  
W System.err:   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:528)  
W System.err:   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:425)  


W System.err:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)  
W System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=375259648, Exec failed  
W System.err:   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)  
W System.err:   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)  
W System.err:   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)  
W System.err:   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  
W System.err:   ... 9 more  

--------- beginning of crash  
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-5  
24066 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mypackagename.appname, PID: 19980  
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void  
java.io.BufferedReader.close()' on a null object reference
```

Some info

1. Above code works on most devices which I have tested. The issue is seen consistently in galaxy s10 with the latest firmware update for android 10.
2. I have tried the above in conjunction with the waitFor function right after the "exec" with similar results.
3. I can do a null check for "reader" but I want to address the root cause which is the IoException.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: on a separate note, use try with resource, looks like the reader is null and you are trying to close

Comment: resource? Yes I realize the reader is null but I believe that's mostly because "exec" failed.

Comment: You have to do try(reader initialization) , doing this will handle closing automatically. Any class which implements Autoclosable can be initialized in try with resource syntax

Comment: Ok. Good to know. Thank you.

Comment: Your IP neigh command failed, check if you can use arp to know if the IP is reachable

Comment: I am not doing it for any particular IP. " Ip neigh" is supposed to fetch all the associated ip's in the ARP table. Btw, the command works in the terminal, just not with runtime.exec

Comment: Can you `exec` _any_ binary? I wonder -- is there some manifest permission you need to state, in order to run `exec()` on some Android versions? Is it even possible that some vendors block `exec()` completely? I'm finding that more and more platform stuff is, in fact, blocked in later releases.

Comment: So far I haven't faced much issue with above. /proc/net was blocked in android 10. I am not aware of any manifest permissions.

Comment: Yeah Google tends to put developers in sticky spots by blocking important stuff.